# validation message not showing in laravel 5.3

Tags: validation, laravel-5.3

I am using validation in laravel 5.3. but error message not getting displayed. what to do?

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

    'name'=>'required|min:2',
    'address'=>'required',
    'email'=>'required',
    'contact_number'=>'required',
    'date_of_birth'=>'required',
    'company_name'=>'required',
    'country'=>'required',
    'city'=>'required',
    'fax'=>'required',
    'telephone'=>'required',
    'picture_upload'=>'required',
    ]);
}
```

in view

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use FromRequests for validation, but I'm pretty sure that the validator takes the `Request` object, but you are passing it an array `$request->all()`, simply change that to: `$request`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :
In Controller

```
$this->validate($request, [
           'name'=>'required|min:2',
           'address'=>'required',
           'email'=>'required',
           'contact_number'=>'required',
           'date_of_birth'=>'required',
           'company_name'=>'required',
           'country'=>'required',
           'city'=>'required',
           'fax'=>'required',
           'telephone'=>'required',
           'picture_upload'=>'required',
    ]);
```

In View

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <strong>OOPS! You might have missed to fill some required fields. Please check the errors.  <strong>

                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>

                </div>
                @endif
```